# C equivalent of IOMemoryDescriptor class

Tags: c++, c, macos, iokit, mach

I'm writing some C code using `IOKit`, and need to use `IOMemoryDescriptor` methods. Unfortunately, I can only compile pure C sources, and that is a C++ class. So, I'm asking if there is some C interface that lets me perform the same operations.

Specifically, I want a function that does pretty much this, but that can be compiled as C:

```
#include <IOKit/IOMemoryDescriptor.h>
extern "C" void CopyOut(mach_vm_address_t src, void *dst, size_t size)
{
    IOMemoryDescriptor *memDesc;
    memDesc = IOMemoryDescriptor::withAddressRange(src, size, kIODirectionOut, current_task());
    // Error checking removed for brevity
    memDesc->prepare();
    memDesc->readBytes(0, dst, size);
    memDesc->complete();
    memDesc->release();
}
```

Comment: You could make a C wrapper for the functions and data structures you want, which you would compile as C++, but you would export with a C interface so you can link it with your program.  But that assumes the problem is you can't link to a C++ library.  If you actually don't have a C++ compiler, then my suggestion won't help.

Comment: @paddy Yes, not having a C++ compiler sums up the problem pretty much. I've hacked the project makefiles to accept an additional C++ file, but would very much prefer to just be able to modify some of the existing C files. Thanks anyway.

Comment: By the way, there's a [kext] tag for kext-related questions, and [xnu] for anything related to the OSX kernel. Those might be more appropriate than [osx] and [mach] in this case, but I haven't edited it as it's debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being based on BSD, xnu has inherited some of BSD's kernel APIs, including the [`copyin` and `copyout` functions](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=copyin&sektion=9). They are declared in libkern.h, and they do pretty much what you're using an `IOMemoryDescriptor` for, but nothing else.

You do mention you're using IOKit - if you need anything beyond this out of IOKit's functionality, you'll pretty much have to go with a C++ compiler, or use C to call mangled names directly.

If you're new to using a weird compiler for building kexts, I'll just warn you that kernel code for x86_64 must not use the [*red zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_%28computing%29) of the stack, as that can't exist due to interrupt handling. If your compiler assumes a red zone is present, you'll get bizarre crashes. Clang and gcc have corresponding flags for disabling the red zone. (`-mno-red-zone`, if I remember correctly, automatically activated via the kernel mode flag) Even if you're using a non-official compiler, linking against an object file built with clang's C++ compiler at the last stage should work fine for wrapping any other C++ APIs.

Comment: Thanks! The `copyin/copyout` are perfect for now, but I fear I'll have the same problem when I start needing other functionality. Still, this is the best answer there could be.  Out of curiosity, do you have any links about calling name-mangled functions from C? I tried it, but the compiler didn't find them.

Comment: The compiler won't find them, you'll have to declare them yourself. The *linker/loader* on the other hand should find them. (i.e. `kextutil -n`) This isn't really a clean long-term solution as you have to explicitly deal with vtable layout etc. and unless it's a one-off, or you're autogenerating your code, you're better off with a C++-to-C glue layer.

Comment: I meant the linker didn't find them (explicitly declared them in `C` source). Thanks.. I wasn't really going to do it, just curious. The *actual* solution here is to start the administrative process that will let me add a .cpp file. I was just hoping I could make do without it.

Comment: Mangling names explicitly should work, as I can't see the code in question I have no idea why it went wrong in your case. I even seem to remember coming across some explicitly mangled C++ names somewhere in xnu's own source code. In any case, I don't recommend it, except maybe as a one-off for a static member function. :-) Good luck with sorting out your original problem!